# how to connect Oracle Database 21c express with DBeaver

Tags: oracle, database-connection, dbeaver

I had some problems setting my oracle XE database with DBeaver, I made this post trying to help anybody with the same problem, see the answer below..

Answer (score 3):

after install oracle database express (21c) open the cmd as administrator and execute this command:

```
lsnrctl status
```

- check if the listner is already runnig
- check your host IP. (ex.: 192.168....)
- check the current port(ex.: 1521 - default).
- check your "Default Service" (ex.: XE)

that is the information you need for the connection.

Now, if the listener is NOT running, use this command to start it:

```
lsnrctl start
```

check if the oracle service is started in your machine:
[image]

check if you have the drivers, if you do not have it, download it and add the JAR's on **Edit Driver Settings**:
[image]

at last, insert your db information and test your connection:
[image]

and it is done...

[image]